# How initialize all element in p:datagrid via javascript?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, datagrid

I have `p:datagrid` in my webapp

```html
<h:form id="musicCloudForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="mainPanelGrid">
    <p:dataGrid id="musicDataGrid" columns="3" paginator="true" rows="12"
                value="#{musicProcess.sounds}" var="track">
      <audio id="gridAudio" preload='none' > 
        <source type='audio/mpeg' id="gridAudioSource"
                src="#{request.contextPath}/audio/#{track.location}/#{track.title}.mp3"/> 
      </audio>
      <p:panel header="#{track.artists}" style="text-align:center"
               styleClass="musicElementClass">
        <p:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="possibilityGrid">
          <p:commandButton id="playMusicButton" style="width: 70px" value="Play"/>
          <p:commandButton id="downloadMusicButton" value="Download"/>
          <p:commandButton id="markMusicButton" value="Mark"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
      </p:panel>
    </p:dataGrid>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Each `p:commandButton` has next id (when I deploy webapp):
`musicCloudForm:musicDataGrid:0:playMusicButton`
Where **0** is number of `p:panel`

I need to initialize all button (all `playMusicButton`, all `downloadMusicButton`, all `markMusicButton`) that exist in this `p:datagrid` in each `p:panel` via Javascript.

I know how do it (simple iteration) but when should I stop iteration? How can I get quantity of each button on current page?

You can offer me another solution !)

Comment: What is initiizing a button according to you

Comment: @Kukeltje, playMusicButton[**i**] = document.getElementById('form:grid: **i** :playMusicButton');